# Why am I getting lvalue required as left operand of assignment?

Tags: c++, random, numbers

Simple stone, scissor, paper program.
I'm getting the error: `[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment.` I can't figure out what's wrong as I'm new to C++ programming, why won't it accept the if statements?

```
// Globale variabler
int PC, User; // For Ã¥ sammenligne input
int Uavgjort = 0;
int user_score = 0;
int pc_score = 0;

int RandRange( int low, int high );
void Compare_values();



int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    cout << "Valg:" << '\n';
    cout << "1. Stein" << '\n'
         << "2. Saks" << '\n'
         << "3. Papir" << '\n' << endl;

    while ( cin >> User )
    {
        RandRange( 1, 3 );
        Compare_values(); // sammenligner brukers verdi og random verdi
        if ( user_score >= 10 || pc_score >= 10 )
            break;
    } // while slutter her

    cout << "Game over!" << "\n\n";
    cout << "Score: \n" 
         << "PC Wins: " << pc_score << " times" << '\n'
         << "You won: " << user_score << " times" << '\n' << endl;

    cin.get();
}

int RandRange( int low, int high )
{
    PC = rand() % ( high - low + 1 ) + low;

    return PC;
}

void Compare_values()
{
        if ( User == 1 && PC == 1 )
        {
            cout << "Stein vs. Stein" << '\n';
            cout << "Uavgjort!" << '\n';
            ++Uavgjort;
        }
        else if ( User == 1 && PC == 2 )
        {
            cout << "Stein vs. Saks" << '\n';
            cout << "Du vant!" << '\n';
            ++user_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 1 && PC == 3 )
        {
            cout << "Stein vs. Papir" << '\n';
            cout << "Dessverre, du tapte." << '\n';
            ++pc_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 2 && PC = 1 )
        {
            cout << "Saks vs. Stein" << '\n';
            cout << "Dessverre, du tapte." << '\n';
            ++pc_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 2 && PC == 2 )
        {
            cout << "Saks vs. Saks" << '\n';
            cout << "Uavgjort!" << '\n';
            ++Uavgjort;
        }
        else if ( User == 2 && PC == 3 )
        {
            cout << "Saks vs. Papir" << '\n';
            cout << "Du vant!" << '\n';
            ++user_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 3 && PC == 1 )
        {
            cout << "Papir vs. Stein" << '\n';
            cout << "Du vant!" << '\n';
            ++user_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 3 && PC == 2 )
        {
            cout << "Papir vs. Saks" << '\n';
            cout << "Dessverre, du tapte." << '\n';
            ++pc_score;
        }
        else if ( User == 3 && PC == 3 )
        {
            cout << "Papir vs. Papir" << '\n';
            cout << "Uavgjort!" << '\n';
            ++Uavgjort;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "Jeg tror du har tastet feil verdi.." << '\n';
        }       
}
```

Comment: First off, read the full error to find out _where_ the problem is. And you can reduce the number of rows/else-if statements by building a string and then print it, and handle the logic for finding a winner slightly different. This will help you avoid mistakes such as the one you have where `=` and `==` get mixed up.

Comment: on which line? you have error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line

```
else if ( User == 2 && PC = 1 )
```

you probably meant

```
else if ( User == 2 && PC == 1 )
                       // ^^
```

Otherwise you're trying to assign `1` to the expression `(User == 2 && PC)` because of operator precedence (where *expression* isn't an appropriate *lvalue*).

Please read compiler error messages thoroughly and so check the lines, where they tell to appear!

Comment: @user3677097 De nada! Don't worry, such happens often and frequently, even with long time experienced programmers ;) ... Could have been even worse if you had used braces `()` for the expressions, it would have left you with a warning instead of an error then.

Comment: I appreciate the beginner-friendly answer, many thanks! And yes, I'm glad it wasn't much worse, this was actually embarrassing.

Comment: best practice is to always use literals as lvalue - `1 == PC` - then if you make a mistake and write `1 = PC` - this is always an error